# Have Legends been implemented for ESRI's REST API?

Tags: arcgis-server, rest

ESRI's 10.0 documentation for [legend](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/mslegend.html) indicates that this url should return a legend:

http://map.floridadisaster.org/GIS/rest/services/Facilities/Critical_Facilities/MapServer/legend

But it doesn't work.  Is there something special I need to do when publishing a mapservice to enable legends?  If not, does anyone know of a url that returns a legend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The REST legend service was added in Service Pack 1.  Has this server had Service Pack 1 installed?  It appears that it has not.

'currentVersion' was added to serveral resources to indicate the version and patch level.  See the latest [ArcGIS 10 API documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/index.html?mslegend.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, this makes me wonder if there's something in the API that tells you what SP is installed.

Comment: 10.0 SP1 returns a currentVersion value of 10.01, not the 10.0 that "vanilla" 10.0 returns.  Just make sure to parse that properly, so you don't accidentally get 10.1!